# ASP.NET MVC 5, IIS Express 8 - not hitting index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-5

I got a controller(named DeficienciesController) with the Index method

```
public ActionResult Index(int? deficiencyReviewId)
        { 
           return View();
        }
```

But when I run the application locally in IIS Express 8 it won't hit the Index method, instead it gets a status code 301 and the browser adds a / to the url.

The weird thing is, when I publish the site to the webserver it runs perfectly fine.. 
When using Html.ActionLink it the a tag looks like this:

```
<a href="/Deficiencies">Deficiencies</a>
```

So I'm expecting it to link to:*http://localhost:49440/Deficiencies*

But when I click it it changes to: *http://localhost:49440/Deficiencies/*

The IIS gives me a "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden" page, because it's trying to browse the folder content.. The controller action doesn't get invoked..

If I add Attribute routing to the controller and action, it all works fine, the Html.ActionLink finds the correct route, but that's not what I want.

My RouteConfig looks like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

The Index action is the only action in the controller which isn't working, other actions works perfectly fine.

*Edit:*

I Wish I could return with a solution to this, but my only working solution to this was to pull the project from the source-control to a new location, and then remove the int value in the action. Then the Index page worked.. Then I made a new action which took the deficiencyReviewId int.. So I really didn't find out what the problem was, but it must be a local problem with my computer, because my colleague got it to work..

Comment: Try to rename your variable deficiencyReviewId to "id".

Comment: I just tried that. I was expecting the ActionLink with a ID to look like this: http://.../Deficiencies?Id=9, but now it looks like http://../Deficiencies/Index/9. Besides the page without an ID still gives a error 403.14.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes you've set `id=UrlParameter.Optional` but you're using `deficiencyReviewId`. When you request `/deficiencies` it's actually expecting: `/deficiencies?deficiencyReviewId=` with a `int?` value.

You could have the method signature like:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? deficiencyReviewId = null)
```

Now `deficiencyReviewId` is an optional parameter so `/deficiencies` will hit your `Index` method

Then to remove the trailing slash, add this to your `web.config`

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>

    <!--To always remove trailing slash from the URL-->
    <rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)/$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>

  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: That was a great suggestion, but this still results in appending of a / at the end of the URL, and a 403.14 page gets displayed. The url ends up like this: _/Deficiencies/?deficiencyReviewId=9_. But I will definitely keep the ´= null´.

Comment: @MartinM Apologies, I missed that part of your question. See my edit

Comment: No worries, however I just tried your edited code and this didn't work either. My colleague just tried running it locally, and that worked. So now I'm trying to pull the project to a new location from the source-control.